# Android :How to make sure views have unique ids so that onRestoreInstanceState works

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout, onrestoreinstancestate

The android developers guide says that views in your activity need to have unique ids in order to restore them in onRestoreInstanceState(). Is this really true, or is it enough to make sure that for each view, all its children have different ids?

If all views in the entire hierarchy should have unique ids it makes it impossible to inflate the same layout resource twice and add two copies to the same view group. Instead, you'd have to do it all programmatically and manually assign unique ids to every single view you use.

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be unique within inflated layout (One .xml resource file). However, .xml resources describing the same layout (for example, landscape and portrait layout views) should have the same IDs

Comment: Thanks for answering. Since asking I found that onRestoreInstanceState only works if views have unique IDs because the views are stored in a SparseArray with IDs as keys. But this doesn't explain what to do. E.g. If you use the constructor ArrayAdapter(Context, int) you are creating a ViewGroup whose children share the same id. You get similar problems when you use the tag <include/> or inflate the same layout twice. Do people just ignore this and accept that onRestoreInstanceState won't work?